# $L^p$ spaces inclusions

Tags: probability, analysis, lp-spaces

Let $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{F},P)$ be a proability space, given $1\le{p}\le{q}\le{\infty}$, is there any inclusion beteween $L^p$ and $L^q$?

Comment: What do you mean by $L^p$, $\int |f|^p < \infty$ or $\mathbf{E}(|X|^p) < \infty$ ?

Comment: Are they not the same? $E[|X|^p]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|X|^p{dP}$

Comment: The difference is the measure $P$ ;)

Comment: Ok, I mean $L^p(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{F},P)=\{X:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}} \text{ measurable}:\int_{\mathbb{R}}|X|^pdP<\infty\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by Hölder's inequality, if $q \geq p$,
$$
\int |X(x)|^p \,P(\mathrm d x) \leq \left(\int |X(x)|^q \,P(\mathrm d x)\right)^{p/q} \left(\int 1 \,P(\mathrm d x)\right)^{1-p/q}
$$
that is, since $P$ is a probability measure, $\mathbb{E}(|X|^p)^{1/p} \leq \mathbb{E}(|X|^q)^{1/q}$.

Comment: So can we conclude that $L^q\subset{L^p}?$ What if we change $\mathbb{R}$ with a generic set $\Omega$?

Comment: Yes, this means $L^q \subset L^p$. I did not use the fact that the domain was $\Bbb R$, so it works as well if the domain is $\Omega$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. So if $L^q\subset{L^p}$ for every $q\ge{p}$ then $L^\infty\subset{L^1}$, can you give an example of $X\in{L^1}$ but $X\not\in{L^\infty}$?

Comment: Yes, $X(x) = |x|^{-1/2}$ with $P(x) = \mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}$